# How to use diff method in Luxon

Tags: javascript, luxon

I currently get a  date from calendar control and using luxon I add days, minutes to it and change it to LongHours format like below:
newValue : is value i get from frontend(calendar control)

```
  let formattedDate: any;
  FormattedDate = DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date(newValue)).plus({ days: 1, hours: 3, minutes: 13, seconds: 10 }).toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_HUGE_WITH_SECONDS)
  console.log(formattedDate);

  const formattedDateParsed = DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date(formattedDate));
  const newValueParsed = DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date(newValue));

  var diffInMonths = formattedDateParsed.diff(newValueParsed, ['months', 'days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']);
  diffInMonths.toObject(); //=> { months: 1 }
  console.log(diffInMonths.toObject());
```

Currently the formattedDateParsed is coming as 'Null'

Can I get some help as how to parse the date so that diff can be calculated

Comment: Can you provide a sample value of `newValue`?

Comment: Friday, January 2, 1970, 8:43:10 AM India Standard Time

Comment: Is that a string or a JavaScript Date? If it is a Js Date I think you can remove the `new Date`, while if it is a string I fear new Date cannot [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) it correctly, you can probably use [`fromFormat`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html#static-method-fromFormat)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few things going on here.

First, `FormattedDate` and `formattedDate` are different variables, so `formattedDate` isn't being set:

```
let formattedDate: any;
FormattedDate = DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date(newValue)).plus({ days: 1, hours: 3, minutes: 13, seconds: 10 }).toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_HUGE_WITH_SECONDS)
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Second, you are converting to a string and then back into a DateTime, using the Date constructor as a parser, which isn't a great idea because a) it's unnecessary, and b) browsers aren't super consistent about which strings they can parse.

Instead, let's just convert once:

```
const newValueParsed = DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date(newValue));
const laterDate = newValueParsed.plus({ days: 1, hours: 3, minutes: 13, seconds: 10 });
const diffInMonths = laterDate.diff(newValueParsed, ['months', 'days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']);
diffInMonths.toObject(); // => {months: 0, days: 1, hours: 3, minutes: 13, seconds: 10}
```